# Роуты и категории rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Есть `post` и `post_category`, `post_category` связана с `post` по `post_category_id`:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :post_category
end

class PostCategory < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :posts
end
```

Есть категория к примеру *Еда*, при добавлении категории есть поле `seo_url`

К примеру:

```
"Еда" seo_url "food"
```

Я хочу для начала получить ссылку на посты вида^

```
site.ru/food/13
```

Как это сделать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Я так понимаю, вас больше интересует разбор ссылок, то есть, [роутинг](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html).*

Если делать наивно, рельсово, ресурсно, то получится поначалу такое (чтобы было удобнее смотреть вывод `rake routes`, я добавил `only: [:show]`, можно потом убрать):

```rb
resources :post_categories, only: [:show] do
  resources :posts, only: [:show]
end
# Категория: /post_categories/:id
# Пост:      /post_categories/:post_category_id/posts/:id
```

Сначала уберём хвосты, ресурсы в множественном числе. Это просто, `resources` принимает опцию `:path`, которая отвечает именно за это. По умолчанию это имя ресурса. А если поставить там пустую строку, то весь сегмент "схлопнется":

```rb
resources :post_categories, path: '', only: [:show] do
  resources :posts, path: '', only: [:show]
end
# Категория: /:id
# Пост:      /:post_category_id/:id
```

Это довольно опасно, поскольку под эти две маски подходит **вообще любой путь из одного и двух сегментов соответственно**. Именно поэтому `path` по умолчанию непустой, он служит "маркером" того, что ссылка относится к ресурсу. Если его убрать — удостоверьтесь, что этот паттерн не "съел" (сделал недоступными) другие ваши маршруты. Для этого, например, можно разместить этот блок *как можно ниже*, ведь **чем выше маршрут, тем выше его приоритет** и тем раньше проверяется совпадение с ним.

### Косметика

В рельсах принято под идентификатором/ключом вида <...>`_id` хранить значение первичного ключа обозначаемой модели. Поскольку на категорию вы будете ссылаться по её "хвосту" (предпочитаемый мной перевод *slug*), есть смысл переименовать соответствующий параметр. Запросто. Опция называется, неожиданно, `:param`:

```rb
resources :post_categories, path: '', param: :name, only: [:show] do
  resources :posts, path: '', only: [:show]
end
# Категория: /:name                      post_categories#show
# Пост:      /:post_category_name/:id            posts#show
```

### Мелкие детали

- В модели есть смысл реализовать `to_param` для генерации ссылок хелперами.
- В контроллерах есть смысл выделить получение записи в `before_action`.
- [`friendly_id`](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) полезен для генерации "хвостов" из пользовательского ввода.

Comment: Как все подробно.. Огромное спасибо. Возникло понимание как что работает. Сейчас попробую все переварить.

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял, тебе нужно что-то типа [friendly_id](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id)