# Как правильно найти пост внутри категории?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
# config/routes.rb
scope module: 'site' do
  root 'main#index'
  resources :post_categories, :path => "/", :only => [:index, :show] do
    resources :posts, :path => "/", :only => [:index, :show]
  end  
end

# app/models/post_category.rb
class PostCategory < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts

  def to_param
    seo_url
  end
end

# app/controllers/post_categories_controller.rb
  def show
    Category.find_by_seo_url(params[:id])
  end
```

`seo_url` - это поле при добавлении категории, типа `"food"`

Теперь статья открывается как

```
site.com/food/22
```

Но проблема в том что теперь она открывается и по адресу к примеру

```
site.com/sadsadas/22
```

Где **sadsadas** может быть любым набором символов.

В чем моя проблема я не пойму?

**UDP D-Side**

Я чуть изменил роутинг вот так

```
  resources :post_categories, path: '', only: :show do
    resources :posts, path: '/:year/:month/:day', only: :show, constraints: { year: /\d{4}/, month: /\d{2}/, day: /\d{2}/ }
  end
```

Хочу получить url такого вида
/category/2015/11/08/id

где 2015.11.08 дата самого поста.

Как правильно из created_at обработать это все в котроллере post?

Так мало информации в интернете, а та что есть на английском.

Буду очень благодарен.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Роуты и категории rails](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/464150/%d0%a0%d0%be%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8b-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b8-rails)

Comment: Нет, это не дубликат, так как там вопрос как это реализовать. А тут я уже это реализовал, но появилась проблема и эту проблему я описал отдельно что бы было более понятно.

Comment: Как же Русский стаковерфлов мало развит еще ( эхх. Не думал что роутинг станет для меня такой огромной проблемой.

Comment: А... понял. У вас тут уже не роутинг, у вас обработка роута в контроллере. А реализация `find_by_seo_url` где?

Comment: Тут видно я туплю, скорее всего не зная как ее сделать. Сейчас погуглю

Comment: Ну, раз её нет, то её ж надо сделать. В этом, видимо, и состоит вопрос. А загвоздка сейчас у вас в том, что вы игнорируете `params[:post_category_id]`.

Comment: Да простите, просто с руби у меня только начало взаимоотношений. Не могли бы скинуть какой-то пример или ссылку на подобное. Никак не могу нагуглить эту логику. Но в любом случае спасибо за наводку, попробую разобраться.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По-хорошему, у вас в вопросе не хватает кода контроллера. Но даже если его приложить, ответ толком не изменится.

Получив запрос по маршруту ко вложенному ресурсу, в контроллере нужный объект есть смысл искать такой же цепочкой вложенности:

```
@post = PostCategory.find_by!(slug: params[:post_category_id]) # достаём категорию
              .posts.find(params[:id]) # из её ассоциации posts достаём пост
```

Обращаю внимание, что используются ["опасные" методы поиска ActiveRecord](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#retrieving-objects-from-the-database) (`find`, `find_by!`), которые в случае отсутствия результата бросают исключение `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound`. Избавляться от него нет необходимости: в средах `production` и аналогичных это исключение приводит к стандартной странице *404 Not Found*, не светя текстом ошибки наружу.

- Для сравнения, использование "тихого" `find_by` вернёт `nil`, если запись не найдётся. Попытка вызвать методы модели у `nil`'а приведёт к `NoMethodError` и ответу *500 Internal Server Error*, что сигнализирует о неисправности в приложении.
- `PostCategory.find_by!` на самом деле алиас к `PostCategory.all.find_by!`. Эти `find`<...>'ы есть у любого `ActiveRecord::Relation`, чем сам `PostCategory` не является.

Comment: Я просто не знаю как вас благодарить. 4 дня я не мог совладать с этим, просто не понимая логику как это работает. Побольше бы таких людей как Вы. Все получилось, поняв логику прописал в post_contriller @posts = PostCategory.find_by!(seo_url: params[:post_category_id]).posts.find(params[:id]) действительно по логам при запросе поста теперь происходит поиск нужной категории и seo_url а несуществующие категории выпадают в ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound.

Comment: Если позволите задам еще два вопроса. Вы и так сильно помогли, поэтому можете не отвечать. Я начав делать полноценный сайт, не много бросился в омут с головой не освоив все. Обязательно это исправлю.

Comment: Так вот, вопрос в том как теперь правильно обратиться к хелперу для получения ссылки на пост? post_category_post GET    /:post_category_id/:id(.:format)         site/posts#show.

Comment: `post_category_post_path(категория, пост)`

Comment: И второй вы писали что использование в роутинге path => '' это довольно опасно. Если не трудно подскажите может ли это быть потом подводным камнем? И как правильнее все таки это реализовать? Или это в принципе не так страшно если правильно расставить блоки в роутингах?

Comment: Это нормально, но с такими роутами нужно просто быть осторожнее. Если этот роут в самом конце, а остальные роуты выше не хватают "любой сегмент на первом месте" (а только константы, скажем, `/profile`), это не должно вызвать серьёзных неприятностей.

Comment: Огромное вам спасибо за советы. Просто словами не передать как вам благодарен. Я надеюсь что этот ответ поможет еще многим кто будет искать решение.

Comment: D-side, а подскажи пожалуйста, что бы вместо id получить title в виде транслитерации, мне как раз поможет friendly_id?

Comment: @bismoney вроде как да, хотя его автор выпустил эту функциональность в виде [отдельной библиотеки `babosa`](https://github.com/norman/babosa).

Comment: Спасибо! То что нужно.

Comment: Привет D-side, подскажи пожалуйста если не занят. Никак не могу уловить логику как обработать в контроллере дату в url. Обновил пост

Comment: @bismoney лучше оформить отдельным вопросом, но в целом ответ -- точно так же. Просто в урле будет три сегмента, из которых надо собрать дату (`Date`).

Comment: Честно говоря, так и не понял как быть с датой в урл.. не поможете? http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/464629/Дата-в-url-как-реализовать