# Дата в url как реализовать?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Всем привет.
Есть роутинг такого формата

```
resources :post_categories, :path => '', :only => [:show] do
    resources :posts, :path => '', :only => [:show]
end
```

Я получаю то что нужно

```
/category/id
/category
```

Как правильно в данный роутинг вписать даты?

```
/category/2015/11/08/id
```

Подскажите пожалуйста.

**UDP**

Нельзя как-то так?

```
  resources :post_categories, path: '', only: :show do
    resources :posts, path: '/:year/:month/:day', only: :show, constraints: { year: /\d{4}/, month: /\d{2}/, day: /\d{2}/ }
  end
```

Остается вопрос как передать параметры year? month? day?

Answer (score 1):

почитайте http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Base.html#method-i-match .
**код из документации**:

```
get 'songs/*category/:title', to: 'songs#show'

# 'songs/rock/classic/stairway-to-heaven' sets
#  params[:category] = 'rock/classic'
#  params[:title] = 'stairway-to-heaven'
```