# Почему не срабатывает тест(Rspec)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Здравствуйте, подскажите пожалуйста почему не срабатывает тест?

```
RSpec.describe QuestionsController, type: :controller do

  describe "Show action" do
    it "renders show template if an item is found" do
      question = Question.create
      get :show, {id: question.id}
      response.should render_template('show')
    end

    it "renders 404 page if an question is not found" do
      get :show, {id: 10}
      expect(response).to have_http_status(:error)
    end
  end
end
```

В контроллере QuestionsController, есть before_action: set_question там

```
def set_question
  @question = Question.find(params[:id])
  unless @question
    render status: 404
  end
end
```

При вводе в адресной строке id вопроса, который не существует происходит редирект на страницу 404. Но при прохождении 2 части теста выскакивает ошибка

```
  Failure/Error: @question = Question.find(params[:id])

     ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound:
       Couldn't find Question with 'id'=10
```

Подскажите пожалуйста что не так.

Comment: См. также [Как правильно найти пост внутри категории?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/464402/181100)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот эта часть метода

```
unless @question
  render status: 404
end
```

никогда не будет достигнута. Дело в том, что метод `find()`, если не найдена запись, генерирует исключение `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound`, что приводит к возврату кода 500, вместо 404. Вам нужно его либо перехватить исключение и в обработчике отдать 404, либо сохранить текущую организацию экшена, но отказаться от `find()` в пользу

```
@question = Question.where(id: params[:id]).first
```

Comment: спасибо, толково

Comment: > что приводит к возврату кода 500, вместо 404

По-моему, это не так. При ошибке `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` рельсы отдадут именно 404-ую ошибку.

Answer (score 0):

Вы ловите `:error`, а ваш контроллер отдает вам ошибку `404`.

Как rspec воспринимает ключ `:error` можно посмотреть [здесь](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/blob/master/lib/rspec/rails/matchers/have_http_status.rb#L318).

Либо укажите статус явно (404), либо используйте ключ `:missing`

```
it "renders 404 page if an question is not found" do
  get :show, {id: 10}
  expect(response).to have_http_status(:missing)
end
```

А вот этот код, как написал [cheops](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/205020/cheops), действительно не нужен. Рельсы сами сделают это за Вас.

```
unless @question
  render status: 404
end
```

p.s. `find` на `where` имеет смысл заменять только в случае, если действия контроллера, в которых не нашелся вопрос, также имеют смысл. Обычно это не так.

Comment: пробовал и 404 и error и :missing, помогло только использование where вместо find.